# The last element in my array overwrite all previous elements

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to save data from JSON into my array, but the last item overwrite the previous values. I have a Student class for storing student info and Skill class for storing student skills.

```
public class Skill {
    public var id : Int = 0
    public var name : String = ""
    public var level : Double = 0.0

    func description() -> String {
        return "ID: \(id), " +
            "name: \(name), " +
        "level: \(level)"
    }
}
```

Student Class

```
public class Student {

    public var studentSkills = Array<Skill>()


    func setCursusUsers(data: [[String: AnyObject]]) {
        for item in data {
            let skills = Skill()
            if let resData = item["skills"]  {
                let stu_data = resData as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                for skill_item in stu_data {
                    skills.id = skill_item["id"] as? Int ?? 0
                    skills.level = skill_item["level"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    skills.name = skill_item["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    studentSkills.append(skills)
                    print(studentSkills[studentSkills.count - 1].description())
                }
                for skill in studentSkills {
                    print(skill.description())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I loop over the skills array and append it to my `studentSkills` array and print the last appended value and the correct value is printed out.

```
for skill_item in stu_data {
    skills.id = skill_item["id"] as? Int ?? 0
    skills.level = skill_item["level"] as? Double ?? 0.0
    skills.name = skill_item["name"] as? String ?? ""
    studentSkills.append(skills)
    print(studentSkills[studentSkills.count - 1].description())
 }
```

Output from the above `print` inside the `for` loop

```
ID: 16, name: Company experience, level: 11.34
ID: 4,  name: Unix, level: 7.4
ID: 17, name: Object-oriented programming, level: 4.59
ID: 3,  name: Rigor, level: 3.24
ID: 7,  name: Group & interpersonal, level: 3.02
ID: 2,  name: Imperative programming, level: 2.98
ID: 6,  name: Web, level: 2.32
ID: 13, name: Organization, level: 1.8
ID: 14, name: Adaptation & creativity, level: 1.14
ID: 5,  name: Graphics, level: 1.12
ID: 10, name: Network & system administration, level: 0.98
ID: 12, name: DB & Data, level: 0.87
ID: 15, name: Technology integration, level: 0.82
ID: 1,  name: Algorithms & AI, level: 0.76
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
```

When I run the following code outside the above `for` loop

```
for skill in studentSkills {
    print(skill.description())
}
```

I get the following output

```
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 11, name: Security, level: 0.45
ID: 7, name: Group & interpersonal, level: 0.21
ID: 7, name: Group & interpersonal, level: 0.21
ID: 7, name: Group & interpersonal, level: 0.21
ID: 7, name: Group & interpersonal, level: 0.21
```

This is the structure of my JSON

```
"cursus_users" : [
  {
    "skills" : [
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      {
        "id" : 11,
        "name" : "Security",
        "level" : 0.45
      }
    ],
    ...
  },
  {
    "skills" : [
      ...,
      ...,
      ...,
      {
        "id" : 7,
        "name" : "Group & interpersonal",
        "level" : 0.21
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

The last element of the skills array overwrite the previous elements, how can I solve this?

Comment: `class Student` is a *reference type,* all array elements are references to the *same instance.*  – This must have been asked and answered before ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000146/swift-array-append-overwriting-other-array-values.

Comment: Thanks Martin R, I'm new to swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always append same skill to the array. And each time you modifying it in `for` loop. You should create new `Skill` every time.

```
for skill_item in stu_data {
     let skills = Skill()
     ...
}
```

Your approach would work if `Skill` was a value type (`struct`), but it is a reference type (`class`) and pointing to the same object.